# Exec system command containing a semicolon in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Seems a silly question, but I'm struggling to find the answer.

I need to execute a really long command directly from `ruby` code to the `shell`, and this command has to contain a `;` character.

If I try to escape it with `\;` doesn't work, if I try to substitute it with `\%3b` it executes but it doesn't substitute `%3b` with `;`, so it doesn't work too.

I tried with `exec`, `system`, ` `#{str}` `, and I can't make it work. It always splits in two my command.

Comment: What context does this semicolon have to work in?  It works fine if it's within a string argument

Comment: It is a variable loaded from a `YAML`. It is inside a variable, I create my command concatenating multiple strings like `var1+var2+semicolon_var+var3`

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us the exact code you're trying to figure out.

Comment: The code is quite huge, I try to create a toy-problem

Comment: I believe what @DiegoSalazar is getting at is that there's a difference between using semicolons in the context of a sub (bash) shell and using a semicolon as an argument to an application. A correct answer needs that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no problem placing a semicolon within a shell command as long as you quote it properly:

```
system('cat file | grep ";"')
# => someline with a ; in it

system("cat #{a_variable} | grep ';'")
# => this will work as well for finding ;
```

I also find that [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) module to be a bit easier to use for odder system calls / quoting issues (but it can be a bit difficult to get it working too -- trade offs):

```
require 'open3'
cmds = %w(grep ';' a_file)
stdout, status = Open3.capture2(*cmds)
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I didn't thought about the quote before and after `'`. Usually I don't work with ruby, today I learned something new. As soon as I can I'm going to accept the answer

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli glad I could help :)

Comment: Interesting the `open3` module, I think I'm going to check it! Thanks again :)

Comment: `open3` is really great and a must-have if you're interested in processing the output of commands.